# Why is [object ErrorEvent] thrown only when the tests are all running?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I'm still trying to figure out the angular tests, and I'm struggling with what a failing test. When I'm running the tests with `ng-test`, the Chrome output shows this error:

```
CustomerComponent should create
[object ErrorEvent] thrown
```

And here is the console content:

```
zone.js:192 Uncaught TypeError: _this.handler.handle is not a function
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js:974)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:60)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:50)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js:54)
    at Observable._subscribe (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/observable/scalar.js:5)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js:42)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:28)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js:23)
    at FilterOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterOperator.call (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js:15)
    at ____________________Elapsed_12_ms__At__Mon_Oct_22_2018_15_18_53_GMT_0200__heure_d__t__d_Europe_centrale_ ()
    at Object.onScheduleTask (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:108)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:401)
    at Object.onScheduleTask (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:297)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:401)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:232)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:255)
    at scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1114)
    at :9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:2090
```

The test file is... Well, the most basic you could find, I suppose.

```
class MockCustomerService {
  public addUserInformations(): Observable<Customer> {
    return of(new Customer());
  }
  public updateCustomerInformations(): Observable<Customer> {
    return of(new Customer());
  }
}

export class PartialTranslateServiceStub {
  addLangs(langs: Array<string>): void { }
  instant (key: string): any { }
}

describe('CustomerComponent', () => {
  let component: CustomerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CustomerComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CustomerComponent, ModalComponent, SecondComponent],
      providers: [FormBuilder, ConfigurationService,
            { provide: TranslateService, useClass: PartialTranslateServiceStub },
            { provide: CustomerService, useClass: MockCustomerService }
      ],
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterTestingModule, TranslateModule.forRoot()]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CustomerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I saw that most of the answers were to add an error handler to the subscribers but that's already done.

In addition, I tried to remake the component from scratch and... When I create a new component, the failing test works successfully. Removing the component make the test fail again.

## Update

A remark: if I comment the tests that failed, then the problem is moved to the next test. Strange.

Comment: can you try setting saourmaps = false flag? It may give you better logs. e.g.

ng test --sourcemaps=false

Comment: The flag doesn't change anything: the error log is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

Problem solved.
The test running before the one that failed was not correctly done, thus impacting the following. Seems like the problem came from the providers that were not properly mocked: for example, instead of a `MockPreviousService`, it was more like `PreviousService`, `DependencyOne`, `DependencyTwo`. It was useless in the test case, so getting rid of the declarations and mocking the service did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to come from a mergeMap. My guess is that the TranslateLoader is the culprit.

Why are you using the real thing in the tests ? I suggest to create a stub of the TranslateModule like this:

```
export class PartialTranslateServiceStub {
    addLangs(langs: Array<string>): void { }
    instant (key: string): any { }
}
```

and in the test remove the translate module and use the stub for the provider:

```
providers: [FormBuilder, CustomerService, ConfigurationService, 
            {provide: TranslateService, useClass: TranslateServiceStub},
            ApiRequestService, AppConfig, HttpClient, HttpHandler],
imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterTestingModule]
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything, but i'm keeping the suggestion that is far more logical for the tests.

Comment: Have you tried to remove all the modules declaration in your test ? And maybe imports: [HttpClientTestingModule] instead of any http

Comment: No, that won't work: I need the modules or else the tests can't be launched. Basically, I've got a clean one, only added the necessary components, providers, and imports and launched it. Still the same problem.

Comment: I removed all mentions to http by using a mocked service, but still the same result...